# Variable isn't updating as it should it be

Tags: python, while-loop, gmail

I am trying to create a program where I am using a module called PGM. That is basically a gmail module. When I get the list of email ids and then get the number of ids in order to get the number of emails I have in my inbox, it works fine, but here is the thing when I put inside an infinite loop to check for any new emails, when I send an email to my inbox it doesn't update the number. It keeps printing the same value.

Here is the code.

```
import PGM,time
from playsound import playsound

mail = PGM.MailReader('username', 'password')

def sound():
    playsound('youve-got-mail-sound.mp3')




def countList():
    List = mail.get_mail_ids()
    count = len(List)
    tracker = count
    return tracker

countList()

while True:
    countList()
    print(countList())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure estimation:

It might be that imap connection should be reopened on every check.

When you try it yourself, a new connection is opened on each time and you get the latest results.

When on loop, the same connection is used and you get the same result, since imaplib does not fetch the results from the server again.

You could try this:

```py
while 1:
    mail = PGM.MailReader('username', 'password')
    # rest of your code logic
```

just to see if it works.

Comment: That's a nice guess at the problem from the symptoms!

Comment: Still no good. I tried doing that but the problem is still there. So the value updates, I have to stop the program and rerun it. I am really clueless right now. I did every thing to the point that my code has unnecessary lines by now.

Comment: UPDATE. I tried again with what you said but I put a break at the last while loop. thought it might have been stuck there, turns out it was! Thank you mate.